# Clear / Reset console at start up

Tags: bash, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Bash Windows 10 Bash (WSL). I need to put `echo -e '\e[9999H'` at the beginning of my `.bashrc` script in order for it to have 24-bit colors in ConEmu. This unfortunately makes my prompt start at the bottom instead of at the top. I then have to `clear` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> the console. So can I put it in my `.bashrc` script so it does that every time I start my terminal?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I have tried many things. Though apparently, it won't work as from the ConEmu dev said if I clear the terminal, the colors will stop working and there isn't currently any work around.

Comment: I thought you said you do use `clear` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>. And if you do, then it doesn't matter if it's by hand or from the script. You need to resource `.bashrc` though for the changes in it to take place in the shell.

Comment: The given echo has nothing to do with color.

Comment: @ThomasDickey https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/953

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently it works when the line with

```
clear
```

is in the `.bashrc` file. Of course after the line with

```
echo -e '\e[9999H'
```

The effect will take place after shell restart or recourcing `.bashrc`. This is done so:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```